# Spring Security - Read configuration programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security with a custom login form. I've customized configuration by using a configuration class:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {          
        http
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/signin")
        .successForwardUrl("/landing")
        .failureForwardUrl("/signinfailed");
    }
...
}
```

As code segment demonstrates my login URLs are not standard. Now I have to hard code these URLs to a lot of places in my application: templates, some of the controllers that have custom login requirements, integration tests. I'm feeling that this practice violates *Don't repeat yourself* principal a little bit. One day if I have to change the URLs, I will need to be sure that all occurrences are modified, etc.

Is there a way to access Spring Security configuration, or at least login form part programmatically, so that I can use configured values without repeating specified values in multiple places?

I've examined `HttpSecurity` class and it seems there is no read access in the class design. A possible option is to build an access mechanism in the configuration class, but it has its own problems (need to hard code default values, poor readability if number of custom items increases, etc.) It would be more convenient if there was a direct way to access the configuration.

Comment: Why you don't want to simply extract your login URL to constants (`private final static LOGIN_URL`) and use it where you need it?

Comment: That's definitely a possible way, but then I have to refer to default values of these URLs if I skip any configuration item. For example I don't specify a success forward URL in my configuration, then I still have to define a constant for it and define it like `private final static String SUCCESS_FORWARD_URL = "/";`. I'm trying to avoid repeating the default values defined in Spring Security implementation.

Comment: You can keep these URLS in external property file. And you can load these on application startup.That way you need to update a single file and these URLs will also be configurable.

Comment: @infiniteRefactor did you find a solution to this?